# jQuery function on window resize

Tags: jquery, window-resize, document-ready

I have this little function in `head`:

```
<script>
    fontsize = function() {
        var fontSize = $(".container").width() * 0.10;
        $(".container #link").css('font-size', fontSize);
    };
    $(document).ready(fontsize);
</script>
```

It's working. On document ready. But I want, also, on window resize.

I've tried with `$(window).resize(fontsize);`, nothing happens.

Comment: What you have should work fine. Can you check the console for errors, and add a working example of the problem to you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, but we cannot see your full code, so you may have placed the resize in a different scope that cannot see your function. The following will avoid that problem.

Shortcut: Use one window `resize` handler, but trigger an initial `resize` event.

e.g.

```
<script>
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var fontSize = $(".container").width() * 0.10;
        $(".container #link").css('font-size', fontSize);
    }).trigger("resize");
</script>
```

*If* your code is not at the end of the `body` element, and you do state it is in your `head` element, your code should also be wrapped in a *document ready handler* to ensure the selectors do not fail.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(window).resize(function() {
            var fontSize = $(".container").width() * 0.10;
            $(".container #link").css('font-size', fontSize);
        }).trigger("resize");
    });
</script>
```

**Note:** `$(function(){ YOUR CODE });` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){ YOUR CODE });`

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/6b7us88f/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the on method on page ready:

```
 fontsize = function() {
        var fontSize = $(".container").width() * 0.10;
        $(".container #link").css('font-size', fontSize);
    };
   fontsize();
   $(window).on('resize',fontsize);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpgc0mmf/2/

Comment: While this works, it's logically no different to what the OP already tried. The issue must lie elsewhere in their code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
<script>
(function($) {

    fontsize = function() {
        var fontSize = $(".container").width() * 0.10;
        $(".container #link").css('font-size', fontSize);
    };

    fontsize();

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        fontsize();
    });

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

It makes use of the `on()` handler in jQuery, attaching it to the window. The callback function will execute your `fontsize()` function.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/p0bw6f11/

Comment: The anonymous function wrapper, in the resize callback, is not needed.

Comment: Not exactly needed, but would be if there were more things to do on resize, down the road.

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure the event on DOM ready

either use it in ready function or attach it using 'on'

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
checkWidth();
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

or

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){....})
```

Comment: `(function($) {` is the shorthand for `jQuery(document).ready(`

Comment: cheers @empric for that, i just mentioned to use on to attach  after DOM ready to configure events